How to Distribute Instances on a Curve in Relative Space witouth having instances rotation moving?
I want to scatter on a curve in relative space in geometry node, but the rotation is not stable and I don't understand why that's the case. See the image it's moving if I rotate the curve object

Normally the rotation is supposed to be based on the tangent and normal of the curve data right? Which is directly based within the curve spline in edit mode, but here it seems that geometry node is re-interpreting the tangent and normal value, and I don't understand why & how I can counter this effect.
Heres the set up I'm using

Edit, to be clear, the problem seem to be linked with the normal of the curve, it's not stable in relative mode, we can see the black overlay like of the curve, and geometry node seem to not be able to evaluate the normal properly in relative space


Try adding the "realize instances" node at the end of your node tree.

(Using Blender 4.2.0)

The reported behavior is labeled as a bug on projects.blender.org. The following solution might be a workaround.

Results

Setup. The origin of the "Cube" object carrying the GeometryNodes modifier is set at (1,0,0), while the origin of the "BézierCircle" curve remains at (0,0,0). Consequently rotation of the curve around the Y axis leads to a Relative motion of the curve. The origin of all "vectors" is set at the tail of the shaft and it remains at (0,0,0).
1. The purple vector is aligned with the local curve Tangent, as output by the Curve to Points node. It is to notice that this vector is not affected by the curve rotation.
2. The yellow vector is aligned with the local curve Normal, as output by the Curve to Points node. As shown in the question, it is to notice that this vector is affected by the curve rotation, and that consequently it does not remain in the plane defined by the curve.
3. The red/green/blue vectors are aligned with the axis of instanced object ("Axes" for demonstration, instead of "Suzanne"). It is to notice that the red vector (i.e. X axis) remains in the plane defined by the curve, after correction of the Rotation output by the Curve to Points node.
GeometryNodes modifier

Correction of the Rotation output by the Curve to Points node is achieved by the 3 nodes with dark green background.
1. The Rotation of the curve is applied to the Z axis using a Rotate Vector node. It is observed that this rotated vector remains perpendicular to the plane defined by the curve.
2. Consequently, the Cross Product between the Tangent vector output by the Curve to Points node and the rotated Z vector remains in the plane defined by the curve.
3. Eventually, the Rotation output by the Curve to Points node is corrected by an Align Rotation to Vector node set such that the instanced object X axis is aligned with the vector computed at step 2.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.0+)

Thanks a lot for your answer!!
But Hmmm StefLancien, it seems that your set up ignore the curve data normals

I am interpreting your comment in different ways. Which one is right ? (1) Indeed, normals are not modified, as your question is about the instanced object orientation. Would you like also the normal (yellow vector in the demonstration) to be corrected ? (2) Or do you mean that you were expecting the normal to be part of the solution, to correct the rotation output by the Curve to Points node?

Hi StefLancien, Thanks for your reply
Well ">>>(1) Indeed, normals are not modified, as your question is about the instanced object orientation.<<<"
The instance object orientation in local mode follow the normal of the curve, the normal of the curve stays consistent no matter how we rotate the curve. therefore even in global (relative) mode, the instances orientations should be aligned with the normals of the curve ">>>(2) Or do you mean that you were expecting the normal to be part of the solution<<<" Yes indeed I was expecting the curve normal to be stable even in relative mode :-)

Note that you successfully made the rotation stable in global mode which already is an achievement and partially an answer to my question as well :-D The problem here is that to replicate the same behavior of local mode, the instances orientation should be also aligned similarly with the curve normal, here they seems to be aligned relatively to the curve object transforms

You wrote "the normal of the curve stays consistent no matter how we rotate the curve". May I ask if it is from some documentation, or your assumption ? Because plugging a Viewer node in the Curve to Points node, and monitoring the Normal output, I still do not understand the numbers I am reading. Whereas the Tangent output makes sense when the curve is rotated. Whatever the curve is rotated, the Normal of point 0 remains (1,0,0), and I still do not understand why....

Hello
If you go in curve edit mode, and enable normal viewport overlay, you will be able to see the normal of the curve, when you rotate the curve object (no the curve data) the curve normal attribute will stay consistent. But somehow in geometry node, it is not the case in relative space

The normal is also known as the "tilt" of the curve

Ive added an image demonstrating the problem is the normal it seems
